# Is it possible to compare other tables within a trigger?

Tags: oracle

I have a database with tables that are chained together with foreign keys, and the last one in the chain also has a foreign key to itself. I want to delete them with cascade on, exapt for the last one in the chain. That one should be set null, unless it's parent record has a certain value. I figured i would do that with a trigger: whenever the last table updated, if the foreign key to itself had been set to null, check the field in the parent record, and if it is the value "default", delete the record in the last table.

However, I haven't found any help online indicting that comparing a parent record in another table.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you won't be able to really delete the record in the last table (mutating table problem), but you could update a status field indicating the record has been logically deleted (untested):

```
create or replace trigger last_table_trig
before update on last_table
for each row
declare
  l_parentField varchar2(100);
begin
  if :new.self_ref_fk is null then
     select p.parent_field into l_parentField from parent_table p
     where p.pk = :new.parent_fk;
     if l_parentField = 'default' then
       :new.status := 'DELETED';
     end if;
  end if;
end;
```

Comment: would it be a bad idea to have php run a sort of cleanup function after to look for those rows and then delete them?? Or would that be considered a bad practice?

Comment: IMO that's absolutely ok, although I'd rather wrap the whole thing in a package function updateLastTable() that issues the update, checks the parent table and performs the cleanup afterwards (without the trigger) - this way, you have all the logic for handling last_table updates in one place.

Answer (score 3):

In general, a row-level trigger on table A cannot query table A.  Doing so would generally raise a mutating table exception (ORA-04091).  So a trigger is generally not the right solution.

Presumably, you have some sort of API (i.e. a stored procedure) to delete records from the parent table.  That API should query this last table before issuing the `DELETE` against the parent table.  It should take care of updating the last table in the chain as well as deleting the data from the parent table.

If you **really** wanted a trigger-based solution, life would get substantially more complicated.  You could work around the mutating table exception by

- Creating a package with a collection of primary keys from the parent table
- Creating a before statement trigger that initializes this collection
- Creating a row-level trigger that populates the collection with the primary keys that were modified by the SQL statement
- Creating an after statement trigger that iterates over the collection and issues whatever DML is necessary (unlike row-level triggers, statement-level triggers on table A can query or modify table A).

If you're using 11g, you can simplify this a bit with a compound trigger with before statement, after row, and after statement sections.  But you've still got a number of moving pieces to try to coordinate.

Comment: the records in the parent table are either being deleted directly or because of a cascade constraint on the parent's parent. All my DB interaction is through php with the OCI8 module

Comment: @AsherMaximum - But you still, presumably, have an API for deleting rows from the parent table in your PHP code, right?  It would be better if you had a layer of stored procedures to handle this sort of data logic.  But nothing stops your PHP procedure from issuing multiple DML statements in order to delete the parent row (obviously, you'll be incurring more network waits as a result of your architecture).

Comment: Yeas, that was my next option, to manually do the cascading delete from within the php. It's a fine option, I was just hoping to avoid it as my table structure has many chained tables together, like so: (-> indicates child record) `location -> building -> floor -> room -> rack -> device -> port`

Comment: The idea being that I want to be able to delete `building` or `location`, and have it cascade down to port. and since port has fk to itself as well, set it to null, unless device.name == default, in that case, delete port

Comment: I guess a better question might have been "can you create an on delete constraint that has a conditional statement to it?"